# Javascript promises inside promise

Tags: javascript, promise

Let's say I have a function call that returns a value, I need to iterate through this value and do another function call that returns a result. 
I need to put all results in an array and display all values in the array when it's finished, for example something like this:

```
var myArray = [];
oneAsyncCall().then(function(val) {
    for (var i = 1; i < val; i++) {
        anotherAsyncCall()().then(function(result) {
            myArray.push(result);
        });
    }
});
```

Where should I do my foreach to iterate the myArray, when everything is finished?

Comment: You should make an array of promises and use `Promise.all`, not push to `myArray` asynchronously.

Comment: That `anotherAsyncCall` looks redundant. Why do you need it to call that in a loop again? Neither `i` or `val` is being used in there.

Comment: of course it's a simplified version, i use a value depending on val

Comment: @Tim Kay, then since `anotherAsyncCall()()` returns a promise, store them into an array, and do as Bergi's comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do something like this. Make a `promise` array and use `Promise.all`

```
var myArray = [];
const promiseArray = [];

oneAsyncCall.then(function(val){
    for (var i = 1 ; i < val ; i++) {
        promiseArray.push(anotherAsyncCall()());
    }

    Promise.all(promiseArray)
      .then(function(dataArrayFromPromises){
           //do things with dataArray which is an array of data from promiseArray promises
       });
});
```

Comment: I've just given the idea about how it should be done and why this doesn't work? @Bergi

Comment: Because `promiseArray` is always empty when you use it. Have a look at emils answer.

Comment: I don't find any reason it would be empty if it gets a value `val` from the first promise and it is an integer. Can you please tell me if I'm missing something?

Comment: Emil is just getting rid of `for` loop by using a `map`. I don't see any other difference

Comment: A `then` callback is always asynchronous. I'll emphasise: empty *when* you use it.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks. I don't know how I forgot that. Updating it

Comment: @Bergi Have updated it. Can you please review this once and possibly can remove a negative vote if it is working fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `Promise.all`. You can use ES6 Promise polyfill or bluebird.

```
oneAsyncCall()
.then(function(val) {
    var promises = [];
    for (var i = 1; i < val; i++) {
        promises.push(anotherAsyncCall()());
    }
    return Promise.all(promises);    
})
.then(function(myArray) {
    // you get all result here
});
```

Additionally, I use following to get rid of `for` statement.

```
Promise.all(
  Array(val-1).fill(undefined).map(() => anotherAsyncCall()())
)
```

So it can be rewritten as

```
oneAsyncCall()
.then((val) => Promise.all(
   Array(val-1).fill(undefined)
   .map(() => anotherAsyncCall()())
))
```

Comment: why anotherAsyncCall()() (double ()()) ?

Comment: the function must be returning another function.

Comment: @Tim On your question, `anotherAsyncCall()()` seems return promise.